# Return value of a function getting corrupted

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
static char sessionid[SESSIONID_LEN+1] = { '\0' };

static void generate_sessionid() {
  char set[] = "0123456789"
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  int len;

  memset(sessionid, 0, sizeof(char) * SESSIONID_LEN);
  for (len = 0; len < SESSIONID_LEN; len++) {
    size_t index = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX*(sizeof(set) - 1);
    sessionid[len] = set[index];
  }
}

char *get_sessionid() {
  if (strlen(sessionid) == 0) generate_sessionid();
  char * dup = strdup(sessionid);
  return dup;
}
```

I call `get_sessionid()` from a different thread (whose function is defined in a different file). When I break in line 2 of `get_sessionid()` and examine the pointer address returned by `strdup()`, this is the value:

```
0x7f7788c004f50
```

Now, when I return from this function and examine the returned value caught in the thread function, the return value is different:

```
0xfffffffffc004f50
```

And subsequently when I call `strlen()` on this returned pointer value, I get a `SIGSEGV` and the reason being `Address 0xfffffffffc004f50 out of bounds`

The two files are part of a big application that have around 30 threads running and many more memory allocations happening elsewhere. I also think memory has been leaked by other threads. But I want to make sure that something is not wrong in the above code.

I verified the above code separately and everything works fine, the return value is not corrupt, i.e, it works perfectly fine when isolated from the rest of the program. But I don't understand why the return value is getting changed when run in the context of the whole program.

**Edit (attachments)**

In the thread function I call as:

**thread.c**

```
#include <header.h>

login_sessionid = (char*)get_sessionid();
```

In the header: **header.h**

```
char * get_sessionid(void);
```

Compiler warnings:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘get_sessionid’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

Both the above warnings are at the line shown (above) of the file `thread.c`

Comment: I don't know whether it was a factor in your problem, but the 'rule of thumb' for headers is: _Use `#include "header.h"` for headers that you write or that are part of your project, and use `#include <header.h>` for headers that are provided external to your project._  If your project is in fact a library, you might use `<header.h>` (or, more likely, `<project/header.h>`) to include public headers from your project, and `"header.h"` to include private headers.

Comment: Oh, ok. I was under the misconception that `"header.h"` was only for headers in the current working directory and `<header.h>` for everything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chances are rather high that the code in the other file doesn't realize that `get_sessionid()` returns a pointer so it assumes it returns an integer and then sign-extends that to create a pointer.

Your compiler is probably warning about undeclared functions; if it isn't, turn up the warning levels until it does.  It should also be warning about converting an integer to a pointer of a different size.

Pay attention to the warnings your compiler gives.  Remember, it knows more about C than you do.

Also make sure the compiler gives you as many warnings as possible.  If you use `gcc`, you should be compiling cleanly with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration`; that's my current benchmark (with `-std=c11` or `-std=c99`).  If your version doesn't support the old style warnings, you can simply leave them out.

Comment: Yes! I noticed this compiler warning in the file (and in the line) that calls the above function: `warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]`
I did declare the function `char * get_sessionid();` in a header file that is included in the calling file. Should I just be casting to a pointer? Or would there be a better way.

Comment: You should declare `extern char *get_sessionid(void);` in a header.  The `void` is necessary; if you don't include it, you've not given a prototype for the function (it is a declaration, but not a prototype declaration; the function takes an unknown but fixed number of parameters).  The `extern` is not necessary; many people omit it, but I prefer to include it for symmetry with those few global variables that must be declared with `extern`.  You should include that header in both source files.  The header lets the compiler check that the usage matches the definition.

Comment: I have declared and included the header like you suggested. I even typecasted at the end. Still the error persists. But I have a lot more compiler warnings that I haven't before paid attention to :)
I think I will need to first try and resolve the other compiler warnings that I have and then try again.

Comment: There's something funny going on, then. Do you have header guards in the header? Do you have correct header guards? Can you show the code: you might have less than 10 lines of header (minimally, 1 one line), and you might have less than 10 lines of C from the second file, including a `#include "header.h"` and a function such as `char *report_sessionid(void) { return get_sessionid(); }`. You'd also include the error messages from your compiler when you compile that code and identify the compiler and platform on which you're running it. With all that, we should be able to see what's the problem.

Comment: Perfect! I have attached the header file and the compiler warnings. More importantly, I noticed I was including the wrong header file! The problem was that I didn't include the required header file but linked the library that contained the definition of the function while compiling.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what @Jonathan Leffler said, if more than one thread can call this routine, there is a race condition allowing different threads to get different id's even though they are separate copies.

One example of what can occur:

- Multiple threads inspect the static session id and see zero so begin initialization and stop.
- One thread at a time completes initialization and makes its own copy. Thus each thread gets a different id.

In general, static storage (with no mutex) and multiple threads do not mix.  This is a classic problem with the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) in multi-threaded environments.

Comment: I actually surrounded the critical section in `get_sessionid()` with a mutex lock. I removed that part (hoping that wasn't the problem) from my question.